# Count the number of four-digit numbers whose digits are either 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5

Tags: combinatorics

For each of the four subsets of the two properties (a) and (b), count the number of four-digit numbers whose digits are either 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5:
(a) The digits are distinct
(b) The number is even

Note that there are four problems here: (empty set) (there are no further restrictions), {a} (property (a) holds), {b} (property (b) holds), {a,b} (both properties (a) and (b) hold)

---

So my question... Idk what the last part is saying?? I completely thought I understood what to do here... that is, the first problem would be a 4-permutation of the set of 5 digits and then the second one would just be where the last digit was 2 or 4, of course, but then this last part has me thrown...

Comment: I say, forget about the second part... your intuition is correct...  consider your last digit first and then the conditions on the remaining 3 digits.  Then consider the two even number possibilities for the last digit and you are done.

Comment: I think the question's saying that you've got a set of $4$ digit numbers, then you take all the numbers like $1235$, which have distinct digits, and numbers like $1232$, which are even but some numbers like $1234$ will fall into both categories so you have to make sure to not double-count them.

Comment: Okay I buy that... Thank you both